# What can the cause of this crashlytics log be?

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I've got a crashing iOS app and after being unable to find a cause from the the crash log provided by iTunes connect I added in crashlytics.  I've now had the same crash event occur by a user (I can't repeat it myself) and have a crashlytics log. However I can't see anything within it which tells me anything more than the original apple log and nothing which points to a cause.  Can anyone point me in the right direction of getting to the bottom of this?
Thanks, Adam

Here's the crashlytics log:

```
0
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x1000000c


Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3b0c1626 objc_msgSend + 5
1  UIKit                          0x32ef950f __32-[UIActionSheet _slideSheetOut:]_block_invoke + 62
2  UIKit                          0x32d413c5 +[UIView(UIViewAnimationWithBlocks) _setupAnimationWithDuration:delay:view:options:factory:animations:start:animationStateGenerator:completion:] + 496
3  UIKit                          0x32e669bf +[UIView(Internal) _animateUsingSpringWithDuration:delay:options:mass:stiffness:damping:initialVelocity:animations:start:completion:] + 146
4  UIKit                          0x32e6691f +[UIView(Internal) _animateUsingSpringWithDuration:delay:options:mass:stiffness:damping:initialVelocity:animations:completion:] + 90
5  UIKit                          0x32ef949f -[UIActionSheet _slideSheetOut:] + 430
6  UIKit                          0x32ef925f -[UIActionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:] + 1078
7  UIKit                          0x32d41057 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 90
8  UIKit                          0x32d40ff7 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 30
9  UIKit                          0x32d40fd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 44
10 UIKit                          0x32d2c737 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 374
11 UIKit                          0x32d40a4f -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 590
12 UIKit                          0x32d40721 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 528
13 UIKit                          0x32d3b6eb -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 758
14 UIKit                          0x32d108ed -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
15 UIKit                          0x32d0ef97 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7102
16 CoreFoundation                 0x304bb25b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
17 CoreFoundation                 0x304ba72b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 206
18 CoreFoundation                 0x304b8f1f __CFRunLoopRun + 622
19 CoreFoundation                 0x30423f4f CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
20 CoreFoundation                 0x30423d33 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
21 GraphicsServices               0x35349663 GSEventRunModal + 138
22 UIKit                          0x32d6f16d UIApplicationMain + 1136
23 starlesson                     0x00072dcf main (main.m:14)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a memory issue in your app.

Somewhere in your app you present an `UIActionSheet`. Now the user pushes a button (`dismissWithClickedButtonIndex`) and the action sheet should slide out (`_slideSheetOut`).

When sliding out a block is trying to send a method to an object that does not exist any more: `objc_msgSend`. This could be the `delegate` of the action sheet.

So you should check the places in your project where you are using an action sheet and the delegates or any other objects it interacts with.